# export Unity3D to WebGL as one file

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is it possible to export Unity3D to WebGL as one file?

I cant find any instructions how it can be done.

Thanks for advices!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Unity3D WebGL build has to be multiple files when it's exported. That's just how Unity structures it's WebGL builds. There's usually an index.html file, as well as 3 or more folders with data on the same level. The majority of the game in contained within two files called "html.data" and "html.js". Most of the other files are config files.

You can zip that entire directory into one file for ease of transport, but you cannot build a single file output.

Comment: Not the answer i want, but looks like it is correct.

Comment: I know what you mean. Sorry. What's the reason you want it to be one file? What problem are you trying to solve? Maybe I can point you in a direction that can solve your problem some other way?

Comment: we have multiple games in our system, one should be loaded on the page  based on conditions. Having only one file simplifies life a lot :).

Comment: Can you dump all the WebGL output into a directory and then treat the directories like files when you move them around?